# How to update an Adaptive card in bot framework

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am building a bot which sends out a Adaptive Card to the user. Once the user clicks on the button in the Adaptive Card, I would like to refresh the card and show a success message to the user.

So far, i tried to fetch the current activity id, handle the action performed by the user and depending on the user response, constructing a new card and setting the activity to the id i have captured earlier.
Still i am unable to update the card.

```
let oldActivId=context.activity.id;
let newActivity = MessageFactory.attachment(newCard);
newActivity.id = oldActivId;
context.updateActivity(newActivity);
```

Comment: Could you please check following [sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot/Bots/TeamsConversationBot.cs)?

Comment: Hi, the node-js sample doesn't work for updating the card. Other scenarios like Mention are working but not the update card. And i am doing the same steps as per the sample, still no luck

Comment: Hi, even with other samples with below code, 
```` 
const newCard = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(responseCard);
 const newActivity = MessageFactory.attachment(newCard);
  newActivity.id = oldActivityId;
await context.updateActivity(newActivity); ````

I receive 200 status code for the update activity, but the message is not getting updated in the emulator or in the Teams Chat

Comment: Could you please try this code?  const card = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(
            "Welcome Card", `Updated count - ${data.count}[
                {
                    type: ActionTypes.MessageBack,
                    title: "Update Card",
                    value: data,
                    text: "UpdateCardAction",
                },
            ]
        );

        card.id = context.activity.replyToId;
        await context.updateActivity({
            attachments: [card],
            id: context.activity.replyToId,
            type: "message",
        });

Comment: Is there any update to the ticket. I have been having the same issue. The card does not update in the emulator, but get a 200 ok.

Comment: Hi @Pawan, try to construct the card inline like this .. 
const card = CardFactory.adaptiveCard({
                $schema: 'http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json',
                type: 'AdaptiveCard',
                version: '1.2',
                ........ 
and then try update the card like below
card.id = activityToBeUpdated;
            let message = MessageFactory.attachment(card);
            message.id = activityToBeUpdated;
            await context.updateActivity(message);